# How to write from array to outputfile?

Tags: c++

I have a vector vec (256, 0) that I use to record type of characters and their frequency from the input file.  So given 3 A's my vec[65] will hold value of 3.  I am trying to write to output file the count non-empty chars in total followed by their ascii character and the frequency of occurrence.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  if (vec[i] != 0)  // if not 0 count it
    count++;

// print the count as the first char in output file
outfile << count;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  if (vec[i] != 0)
    outfile << (char) i << vec[i];
```

Given input "a bb c" what I want is:

4a1b2c1

But what I get is:

5

1 2a1b2c1

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'd start by initializing your for-loop correctly rather than using an *indeterminate* value. this: `for (int i; i < 256; i++)` is *wrong*.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.

Comment: And you may find `std::accumulate()` and `std::isalnum()` equally helpful.

Comment: I don't want isalnum() since I want input to work for all 256 chars in the ascii table, not sure why I would need accumulate either, I don't want to add them just print them and their occurences

Comment: How do you propose to "print" a ctrl-g (bell) or a form feed, a tab, a linefeed, a carriage return, etc, in a way that conveys something meaningful to the user? In short, how do you plan to "print" the unprintable ? (and std::accumulate()) would replace your first for-loop *entirely*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file looks like this: "a bb c\r\n" instead of "a bb c". This means that you have five character types: one '\n' (ASCII code: 10), one '\r' (ASCII code: 13), two spaces (ASCII code: 32), one 'a', two 'b' characters, and one 'c'. So your code works correctly! The problem is, when you print '\r', '\n' and ' ' into your output file, they will show up as whitespaces.

If you remove the newline from the input file, to get "a bb c" as input, the output will be this: "4 1a1b2c1", because the ASCII code of space is less than the ASCII code of 'a'.

Comment: Thanks, I mistyped it should be as you said

Comment: Did the output change after correcting the typo? If yes, please update your question!

Comment: The output is still not what I want. Given an string "abbc" I want 4a1b2c1  but I get 4,then a line is skipped, then 1a1b2c1

Comment: I think this is so because you've put a newline at the end of the input by pressing [Enter] when editing the input file. See my updated answer. If you eliminate the newline from the input file in order to make it really contain "abbc" only, you will get this output: "3a1b2c1".

Comment: I see, how do I ignore '\r', ' ' and '\n' chars?  Like if(vec[i] != ' ' || vec[i] != '\n' || vec[i] != '\r' || vec[i] !=0 ) {do stuff}  ?

Comment: Open the input file, press Ctrl+End, then press Backspace. Now the cursor should be at the end of the first line, after the 'c' character. Now save the input file.

Comment: Given input "abc" after pressig Ctr+End and Backspace I still get 4, then skipped line, and only then 1a1b1c1 but I want 3a1b1c1, and I need all 256 chars so I was thinking I do if(vec[i] != ' ' || vec[i] != '\n' || vec[i] != '\r' || vec[i] !=0 ) {//print to output} is this okay?

Comment: What bytes does your input file contain? You can check the bytes of a file in a hex viewer. For example, if you use Total Commander, select the input file, press F3, then 3. I guess there is still a '\r' or '\n' at the end of the file. These show up in the hex editor as 0d and 0a.

Comment: As I said, you can also restrict the set of counted characters by running your loops not from 0 to 255, but, for example, from 33 to 126 (these are the non-whitespace, printable characters, check out the ASCII code table: http://asciitable.com).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using hexdump and indeed the data contain 0a.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have one newline and two space characters in you input. Then, after the five for the total number of characters, you get the newline printed, then the number of times it appears, then a space character, and the two, and then the other characters.

**Edit**

I understand you do not want to include newline and space characters and similar control characters into your counts. Then you would to have to exclude them when you fill your vector. Assuming your currenct character is in a `char` variable named `c`, you would then use something like

```
if(c > ' ') {
    /* do the stuff of increasing the count for c as you do it currently */
}
```

Comment: OK I tried with input: "abbc" and still get:  4 skip 2 lines and then 1a1b2c1   but I want it to print  4a1b2c1

Comment: input "abba" I read it using ifile.open(fileName, ios::binary)

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  if (i != 32 && i != 10 && i != 13)  // don't count ' ' (spaces) and other stuff
    count += vec[i]; //(not all vec[i] values are 1, 98 for instance is 2 (bb))

cout << count;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
 if (i != 32 && i != 10 && i != 13 && vec[i] != 0)
    cout << (char) i << vec[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a map to store the counts.

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f2339db3a2dfa74589d89ca4879ebd8c-f57662db7ed12f7d4058b050081d90a7)**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

std::map<char, size_t> histogram(std::string const& input)
{
    std::map<char, size_t> freq;
    for (auto ch : input)
        freq[ch]++;

    return freq;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "hello world (or read this from a large file";

    auto frequencies = histogram(input);

    for (auto& entry : frequencies)
        std::cout << "'" << entry.first << "': " << entry.second << "\n";
}
```

This prints

```
' ': 8
'(': 1
'a': 3
'd': 2
'e': 4
'f': 2
'g': 1
'h': 2
'i': 2
'l': 5
'm': 1
'o': 4
'r': 5
's': 1
't': 1
'w': 1
```

Oh, and for unprintables,

```
std::cout << "char: 0x" << std::setw(2) << std::ios::hex << entry.first;
```

would be nice to get `0x07` for ASCII 7 etc.